# How to filter records based on parent object in process builder?

Tags: process-builder, fields, field-update

I am working on process builder. If the record passes the criteria node, I have added another filter before it tries to update the fields on the object. My object has a lookup to Account object, and my filter criteria states that Account field should not be null in order to update the field value. However, I want to add one more criteria which checks the email of the owner on the related account object. Process builder is only allowing me to add filters on the Account lookup field, but not on the fields of the Account object itself. Any idea how to go around this? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's right Ayush, in the criteria within the Action itself, you cannot select fields on related objects.
Either put the Account owner email criterion in the diamond criteria node, or add a custom field to your object which gets the Account owner email.